# Using Mediaplayer within a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm still trying to understand fragments and how they work. I have a fragment that inflates a layout. I am trying to play a sound when a button is pushed but I am coming across some problems with the mediaplayer.

The code is:

```
private void playSound(int resId) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Tab1Fragment.this, resId);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(Tab1Fragment.this);
    mp.start();
}
```

The error is: `The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (Tab1Fragment, int)`

I tried using `getApplicationContext()` to no avail.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Use getActivity().  It's a method within the Fragment API that returns the Activity the Fragment is attached to.  Just make sure 100% that it's *always* called after `onAttach()`.

Comment: @DeeV worked perfect! Thnanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in onCreateView method of your fragment class and it will be working fine.

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity, R.raw.songname);
```

Now you can call it's start method on your button click listener. 
Make sure to make the `MediaPlayer mp;` global for fragment class so you can use it afterwards.