# trying Using Mediaplayer within a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a beginner of programming, and trying to use MediaPlayer in a Fragment,
but have the same problem following:

[Using Mediaplayer within a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073471/using-mediaplayer-within-a-fragment/14440656#14440656)

this person seemed solve the problem so quickly, but I couldn't understand.
please somebody help me

What does it mean by "Use getActivity()" and "called after onAttach()"?
I put "getActivity()" in MediaPlayer.create() method like below:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create( getActivity , resId );
```

Then compile error was disappeared but I got error when I try to turn on the 
application on a device.  What should I do?

Does the Class have to extends Activity, Though I want to use Fragment class ?
Does the Class have to have internal class which extends fragment??
I'm confusing.

I found the following URL...
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html How do I add a Fragment to an Activity with a programmatically created content view

Answer (score 2):

did you put the `()`

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create( getActivity() , resId );
```

the getActivity gives the Media Player the context it needs.
think of it like using `this` from within a activity

```
//in an activity you would do this
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create( this , resId );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **getActivity().getBaseContext()**