# Play audio from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play audio from within a fragment but it's giving me errors on Media Player. The error is like this

> Cannot resolve method 'create(com.xyz.packageName.ConnectFragment,int)'

**Code line is this**

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ConnectFragment.this,R.raw.thenights);
```

Here what should be in context's portion of constructor parameter - (**ConnectFragment.this**,R.raw.thenights).

**Error after building project is**

> Error:(39, 25) error: variable declaration not allowed here

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which method are you calling this code in your fragment ?

Comment: It's getting called from an inner class within connectFragment class. the call to method containing my media player code is in connectFragment class

Comment: should I post the whole fragment class code ... will that be enough?

Comment: Yes please post it.

Comment: Please post the fragment class code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.thenights);  

//OR
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.thenights); 

//OR
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.thenights);
```

Comment: All three options giving same error 'Declaration not allowed here'

Comment: then why are you give answer to other
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45211670/6666677

Comment: because that is the case of running only one mp3 ... he wanted to play a single sound on button from within a fragment . I want to play different songs .... on user's click .. so single declaration won't be enough in my case

Comment: that's the right answer but only for that case where you want to play a single sound ... I think you've got my point. If you feel that my that answer is correct kindly up vote that.

Comment: i've updated my question with the error ... it's a compile time error so nothing like error appears in log

Comment: Have you try to add `getActivity()` for context. You can't use like `Fragment.this` for context reference.

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer accepts applicationcontext so you can do

`MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.raw.thenights);`